# I'm burninating [data]

Tags: discussion, tags

A recent tag wiki suggested edit review brought my attention to our [data](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data) tag, which currently has the following two questions in it:

- [What data are OBD-II scanners capable of logging?](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/35184/what-data-are-obd-ii-scanners-capable-of-logging) (this one is about OBD-II data)
- [Motor Industry reliability data - is there a source?](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/33565/motor-industry-reliability-data-is-there-a-source) (this one is about reliability data)

I'm removing the tag from these two questions. This isn't a discussion, I'm just making an executive decision and letting you all know. The two questions above are there if somebody wants to repurpose this tag into something consistent and valuable then put it back on one of them.

I don't think this tag should be blacklisted as so far it hasn't come up often enough to be problematic.

I rejected the tag wiki edits (which were defining it in the OBD-II sense) since they were incompatible with 50% of the questions that had that tag (heh), but if y'all decide that tag has value with that meaning or another and somebody wants to re-suggest those edits, fwiw I have no objections.